# ¿Se puede crear un funcion dentro de otra funcion en postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una base de datos y dentro de ella tengo la funcion **crear_funciones** y dentro de la funcion crear_funciones quiero crear otra funcion **transaccioncuentas** para poder crearla en otra base de datos como se ve pero me marca un error en el **DECLARE** de la funcion **transaccioncuentas**. ¿Alguien sabe si se puede hacer esto?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.crear_funciones(
    rfc character varying)
RETURNS character varying
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$

DECLARE
comando VARCHAR:=('CREATE FUNCTION');
BEGIN
/*RETURN 'HOLA MUNDO';*/

PERFORM * from dblink('dbname='||rfc||'','
     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.transaccioncuentas(
    _post character varying[])
RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE ''plpgsql''

AS $BODY$

DECLARE
    _fecha timestamp;
    _ejercicio INTEGER;
    _periodo INTEGER;
    _tipopol INTEGER;
    _cuendestino character varying(32);
    _corigen character varying(32);
    _cdestino character varying(32);
    _referencia character varying(100);
    _deposito DECIMAL (12,2);
    _porigen INTEGER;
    _pdestino INTEGER;
    _maxfolio INTEGER;
    idultimapoliza INTEGER;

BEGIN

    _fecha = _post[1];
    _ejercicio = _post[2];
    _periodo = _post[3];
    _tipopol = _post[4];
    _cuendestino = _post[5];
    _corigen = _post[6];
    _cdestino = _post[7];
    _referencia = _post[8];
    _deposito = _post[9];
    _porigen = _post[10];
    _pdestino = _post[11];

    _maxfolio := (SELECT getmaxfolio(_periodo,_tipopol,_ejercicio));
    _maxfolio = _maxfolio + 1;

    INSERT INTO polizas(ejercicio,folio,periodo,tipopol,concepto,fecha,cargos,abonos,status,status2,referencia) values(_ejercicio,_maxfolio,_periodo,_tipopol,_cuendestino || ' ' || _referencia,_fecha,_deposito,_deposito,1,1,_referencia)
    RETURNING id INTO idultimapoliza; 

    INSERT INTO detalle_polizas(idpoliza,ejercicio,periodo,tipopol,nummovto,idcuenta,tipomovto,importe,concepto,referencia,fecha,idsegneg,id_padre,status2) 
    VALUES(idultimapoliza,_ejercicio,_periodo,3,1,_corigen,0,_deposito,_cuendestino,_referencia,_fecha,1,_porigen,1);

    INSERT INTO detalle_polizas(idpoliza,ejercicio,periodo,tipopol,nummovto,idcuenta,tipomovto,importe,concepto,referencia,fecha,idsegneg,id_padre,status2) 
    VALUES(idultimapoliza,_ejercicio,_periodo,3,1,_cdestino,1,_deposito,_cuendestino,_referencia,_fecha,1,_pdestino,1);

    return idultimapoliza;

END;
DELIMITER ;

$BODY$; ') as db(crear_funciones character varying); 
RETURN comando;
END;

$BODY$;
```

Comment: No se si te refieras a lo siguiente, pero puedes leerlo en el siguiente enlace y podría serte util:
[Funciones anidadas dentro de postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4610af1f0801310547y5d017850v2ded16119db3012d%40mail.gmail.com)